# How to set column in PhpSpreadsheet to String

Tags: php, spreadsheet, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

im trying to save my data from excel to database.

in my column i have data like this `6.0110000`, when i save my data changed to `6.011`.

how i can keep my data to `6.0110000`, look like it remove all `0` after comma.

my code is like this:

```
$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($file['tmp_name']);
$sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->removeRow(1)->toArray(null, true, true, true);
print_r($sheetData);
```

Comment: I used  simple trick, try to add  `'` so will be: `'6.0110000` (on excel)

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708459/getting-cell-as-string-in-phpexcel-by-column-and-row