# PHP Spreadsheet leading zero in cell not working

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I copied this code from *PhpSpreadsheet's* documentation and it does not work.
This example can be found on this page:
[LINK to PhpSpreadsheet's documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/)

From the above link

---

[image]

---

My code:

```
$sheet->getCell('A2')->setValue(19);
$sheet->getStyle('A2')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0000'); 
// will show as 0019 in Excel
```

**But** its not working and this is the result:

[image]

The expected value of cell $A2 should be **0019** but it shows **19**.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Does it need tol be a numeric value or is a string okay?  Con you create a CSV rather than a spreadsheet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get phpexcel to keep leading 0s in phone numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635178/how-to-get-phpexcel-to-keep-leading-0s-in-phone-numbers)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @PunitGajjar but it's still not working :(

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you use a CSV format try to use Xlsx, I think styling in CSV is not working.

I think this is already issued and there's no solution yet. I'm also looking for the solution but the solution i only found is not use CSV.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/2230

Comment: Yes I'm using csv format, I'm making a utility for some program and the program only accepts csv format @Alfredo

Comment: MS Excel's CSV loader will always convert a numeric string into a number value when the csv file is opened in Excel; that's behavior that only MS could change. The only way to retain that formatting is to use the Data/Get&Transform/FromCSV option inside MS Excel that allows you to specify the rules for import of the different columns -This is issue in their github and I'm also looking for this solution. you can try this and there's no guarantee that this will work
 
$worksheet->getCell('A1')->setValueExplicit(
    '0000', 
    \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType::TYPE_STRING
);

Comment: Thanks for the reply bro but it's still not working.

Comment: This is also my problem ahahhaha, But I don't see any solution in this and almost tried everything maybe someone know the solution.