# PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat - 01234 (zero truncated)

Tags: php, excel, numbers, download, excel-2007

I want to write a value in Excel file, for example `0123456`, when I open the excel file I can only get the value `123456`; by default `0` is automatically truncated, even I used the below code:

```
$objExcelWriter->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AM')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

I want to display exactly the value `0123456`, please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: Got solution in existing post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054312/php-excel-correct-format-for-strings-numbers-beginning-with-zero

Answer (score 0):

```
$objExcelWriter->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AM')
    ->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0000000');
```